# Custom ArrayList to Spinner

Tags: java, android, arraylist, spinner

I want every name from my `ArrayList` into a arrayadapter or spinner.

I have a `ArrayList<Type> types`

`Type` class:

```
public class Type{

   int id;
   String name;

   public Type(int id, String name) {
       this.id = id;
       this.name = name;
   }
}
```

And i also have a `Spinner` now i want in the spinner all the names from the arraylist.

but if i choose a name from the spinner i also want to know what the id from the name is.

Anyone who knows if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i added this in my class `Type`

```
public String toString() {
        return id;
    }
```

and set the list to a ArrayAdapter

```
 ArrayAdapter<Type> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Type>(Checklist.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, types);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    //this Logs the correct id (:
    Log.e("test", String.valueOf(types.get(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).id));
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks on the item, you will get a callback in a method like this:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id);
```

The adapter interface specifies the [getItem(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItem(int)) method, which you can use to obtain the object. In your case, the item the user clicked on is a "Type" object.

Something like this will work:

```
Adapter adapter = listView.getAdapter();    // somehow obtain your adapter
Type item = (Type) adapter.getItem(position); 
int id = item.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get the `onItemSelected` callback from the `Spinner` when an item has been selected it provides the index into your ArrayList that you can use to look up which `Type` has been chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Override the `getItemId(int position)` in your custom `ArrayAdapter<Type>`.

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position){
    return getItem(position).id;
}
```

When the `OnItemClickListener#onItemClick()` is called it will pass your `id`

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    doSomethingWithYourType(id);
}
```